# Homomorphisms from finitely generated modules and flat modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote, question 24 in section 10.5 asks the reader to prove the equality of these statements: (1) $A$ is a flat $R$-module and (2) for any injective $R$-module homomorphism $\phi : L \rightarrow M$ with $L$ finitely generated, $1\otimes \phi : A\otimes _R L \rightarrow A\otimes _R M$ is also injective. (1) clearly implies (2) by definition but the converse isn’t as obvious. My thoughts are to show that every module can be embedded in a finitely generated module so that we can always restrict $1\otimes \phi$ to give an injective homomorphism from a module that isn’t necessarily finitely generated, yet I don’t think this is the right approach. Sorry if this is a trivial question, I just don’t want to continue without understanding this. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call a module satisfying condition 2 *finitely flat*. We need to prove that
finitely flat modules are flat.

We may as well suppose that $L$ is a submodule of $M$. Let $A$ be finitely flat,
and suppose that $\alpha$ is an element of $A\otimes L$ which becomes
zero in $A\otimes M$. We can write $A=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i a_i\otimes l_i$
where $r_i\in R$, $a_i\in A$ and $l_i\in L$. So we can replace $L$ by the
submodule $L'$ generated by the $l_i$.

By finite flatness, $\alpha=0$ in $A\otimes L'$ and so $\alpha=0$ in $A\otimes L$.
Therefore $A$ is flat.

Comment: Ah that’s clever. I assume you mean alpha instead of A before the sum? Thanks for the help.